# How to prevent duplicate title tags on dynamic content

Tags: php, url, seo

Links on the website I am making currently look like this:

```
http://www.example.net/blogs/151/This-is-a-title-in-a-url
```

My php system pulls out the id (`151` say) and uses that to pull to content from my database. The text afterwards is effectively ignored (much like stackoverflow uses).

Now my problem is that this creates duplicate titles that Google will sometimes index and I lose SEO as a result:

```
http://www.example.net/blogs/151/This-is

http://www.example.net/blogs/151/
```

What is the best way to make it so that google and other search engines only see the correct full link so that I don't end up with duplicates and get the best ranking possible?

**EDIT:** I notice that with stackoverflow site that you get dynamically redirected to another page? How do they do that?

Comment: [`rel="canonical"`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394), although you could also check & do a permanent redirect to your 'correct page'.

Comment: Check the URI for the title and compare it to the correct one. If they differ, make a redirect with the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a URI to be canonical.

When you get a request for `http://example.com/123/anything` then, instead of ignoring the `anything`, compare it to the canonical URI.

If it doesn't match, issue a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect.

---

A less optimal approach would be to specify the canonical URI in the page instead of redirecting:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/123/anything"/>
```

Comment: Is this how stackoverflow do it? I notice that if I delete half the title from the url I get some sort of redirection? How is this done?

Comment: Besides storing the ID of the article, you may store the "SEO friendly" version of the title in the database. This way, you check for the ID in the URL, check its "SEO friendly" name in the database and in the URL, and if they differ - redirect to the correct URL (ID+"SEO friendly" name from the DB). Also, it is wise to include the `rel="canonical"` tag as it has already been suggested.

Comment: Stackoverflow does issue a 301 Moved Permanently. You can see the URI in PHP with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and redirect with `header()`

Comment: As for StackOverflow, besides doing the check I outlined in the above comment, I suspect they also keep a list of revisions to the "SEO friendly" title.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent...that is what I get when I try to use header()

Comment: That's [easily resolved](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent&aq=f&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent&aqs=chrome.0.57j58.6614j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com");